# Array element overwritten with last in C and SDL

Tags: c, pointers

I know something like that has been asked a bunch of times but none of the other answers I found were helpful.

Basically I'm trying to create a bunch of blocks (custom struct) with an offset. I create a new SDL_Rect with custom location and add it to a block with other properties. Then add that block to an array. The problem is that in the end, all blocks share rectangle from the last one created (other properties are fine).

Can someone please help me with this? I have no idea how this could be a pointer issue because I'm not reusing anything but apparently it is.

```
    SDL_Color blockColors[] = 
    {
        {192,  0,  0,  0},
        {192, 64,  0,  0},
        {192,128,  0,  0},
        {192,192,  0,  0},
        {  0,192,  0,  0},
        {  0,  0,192,  0},
    };
    int blockColorCount = 6;

    Block* blocks = malloc(sizeof(Block) * blockColorCount * 25);
    int blockCount = blockColorCount * 25;

    //blocks creation
    for (int y = 0; y < blockColorCount; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 25; x++)
        {
            SDL_Rect blockRectangle;
            blockRectangle.x = 25+x*18;
            blockRectangle.y = 180+y*18;
            blockRectangle.w = 18;
            blockRectangle.h = 18;

            Block tempBlock = {&blockRectangle,blockColors[y],1,false};
            blocks[y*25 + x] = tempBlock;
            printf("%d %d\n",blocks[y*25+x],&tempBlock);

        }
    }
```

```
typedef struct
{
    SDL_Rect* rect;
    SDL_Color color;
    int health;
    bool dead;
} Block;
```

Comment: Your putting the address of an expiring automatic variable in each block you created. Each and every `SDL_Rect *` in each and ever `Block` ends up being a dangling pointer once all this madness is done. Even the last one is no longer valid. Since each one gets exactly one `SDL_rect`, dare I asky why you don't just make `rect` a concrete object rather than a pointer to said-same ?

Comment: Why do you declare the `rect` member as a pointer? Why not a plain non-pointer object (as in `SDL_Rect rect;`)?

Comment: SDL_Rect blockRectangle;  >>> Please try doing malloc instead of using stack variable pointers. SDL_Rect * blockRectangle = (SDL_Rect *)malloc( sizeof(SDL_Rect));

Comment: I made the rect as a pointer because most SDL functions ask for that. Will blocks[y*25 + x] = tempBlock; not copy the block to the array?

Comment: Yes that assignment will copy the `tempBlock` structure. The problem is that it's a *shallow* copy, which will copy the *pointer* `&blockRectangle`, not the structure it points to. And as you know about the address-of operator`&`, why not simply use it when you need to pass `rect` to the functions needing a pointer? The less pointers you have, the simpler your code will become. And the simpler it becomes, the less chances of problems.

Comment: Removing the pointer from the struct solved everything. Thanks to everyone for helping me. I thought that it was a full copy with pointer properties as if I declared it somewhere in the script and that I could avoid a bunch of conversions but this makes more sense.

Comment: How can I mark an answer if it's in the comments?